# didSelectRowAtIndexPath when is it being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I am trying to make an app where you click a cell in a list of cells on the uitableview and it opens a cooresponding PDF file. To do this i want to pass the title of the cell in between to seperate classes. I have one class called "IndianaSpecificLawsView" that manages the UITableCells and this is the code for it

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString* cellTitle = [[cell textLabel] text];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@" (Pt1 Cell Title == %@",cellTitle);

    // saving an NSString
    [prefs setObject:@"cellTitle" forKey:@"cellTitle_String"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

And I am trying to use NSUserDefuaults to pass it but when i put in the NSLog to test it the NSLog is never getting printed. Do i need to call this method? I assumed it was being called when i pressed the button but it is not. Thanks!

Comment: did you set the datasource and delegate objects for you tableview?

Comment: For the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, you'd need to ensure that the tableView delegate has been set. (It belongs to the UITableViewDelegate protocol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `viewDidLoad` method and set `UITableView`'s data source and delegate:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}
```

And implement `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

Comment: These are all static cells though. So do i still need to "implement" these protocols?

Comment: No, then you don't need to do it.